# Web Service with Java from XML Database to XQuery

Tags: java, xml, web-services, rest, xquery

This is my first programming in my life.
Now I MUST create Web Service(Rest but when Soap is suitable way for this situation,i try Soap method ) with Java.
From XML Database in own FTP Server pick up data and return.

From XML Data transform to XQuery with Java or different Methode.

XML DB →REST Web service (XQuery) →XML DB return
OR more simple way i would like to choose.

XML Database : Text, Bild, URL,name, year.

I tried to create the web service for couple of week.
install software and plug-in, in addition to checking to run all of them;

BaseX,
Tomcat 7.0.62 localhost, 
Jersey 1.19, 
Eclipse 4.4 Luna and plug-in, 
JAVA 　1.8, 
JDK 8, 
JAXB

I read tutorials for example:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0901rodrigues/

But it did not work. I am getting below exception:

```
enter code here
`javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`
```

root cause:

```
enter code here
`com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`
```

I am having problems finding useful resources to help me approach this issue, and I would appreciate advice on how to proceed.

Comment: This stuff is pretty hard. Not normally suitable for a beginner.

Comment: you need someone's help, like professor or try topcoder maybe

Comment: I downvoted your question, bu please don't be discouraged by that it is simple how we filter questions on SO. So first of all welcome to SO! Unfortunately, your question is very unclear on what you are trying to achieve and why you do the stuff your describe. It sounds like you are pretty much lost and I feel your questions is very unspecific and might simple be not a good fit for SO.

Comment: @dirkk 
thats true. Because I am not sure about Web Service and how can i creat Web service. I just already now "Web service can connect computer to computer".  Not the less i must create now the Web Service. In addtion I dont know so much about using for stackoverflow.

Comment: You might want to check this beginners guide, maybe this can get you started: http://www.swennenhuis.nl/basexfordummies/BaseX_for_dummies.pdf However, I get the impression that you are aiming too high and should get started at fundamentals of programming instead of insisting you MUST implement a web service. Whoever needs this should get someone with experience to do this...

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear whether Java is a real requirement, or rather a technology you think you would need. If you can do without it, you could have a look at a native XML database. For open source, look at eXist or BaseX. They all come with their own HTTP binding mechanism, and even REST services libraries and frameworks.

Comment: Take a look especially at RESTXQ (https://docs.basex.org/wiki/RESTXQ), an XQuery technologie to build REST application, so exactly your use case. Using basex you can just start `basexhttp` if you download the zip version (http://basex.org/products/download/all-downloads/) and you will get an example REST application at `localhost:8984`. I doubt it will get any easier than that...

Comment: @dirkk Thank you so much for additional information. I check the webseit and try again! and Can I ask more question about the new Methode?

Comment: @Florent
Thank you for advice. 　I mean ,XML DB →(XML) →REST Web service →(XQuery) →XML DB return So I thought i need Java. I check also eXist or BaseX

Comment: @dirkk
I read the Links and https://github.com/BaseXdb.
But I need more explain like the URL https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19/index.html . I did not understand, how can I the Application for  my case(connect XML Database by web Service). 
Thank you.

Comment: If there is something from http://docs.basex.org/wiki/RESTXQ that you cannot achieve, it is probably better to create a new question about the exact thing you can't achieve, rather than a laconic "I don't understand" in a comment.

Comment: @FlorentGeorges Thank you for ur Advice! I check more what i did not understand exact.  Anyway it looks like not so easy for me,too.  Thanks.

Comment: @FlorentGeorges Can I ask a question? Finally my XML DB is running and  I wrrited RESTXQ by XQuery also. but I m not sure, how and where can i the Restxq data. Could you please give me some advice for that?

Comment: If you get a specific question on RESTXQ, I suggest you post another question about that specific problem/question. You can post a link here for follow-up. Besides, there seems to miss something in "`how and where can I the Restxq data`", like a verb or something :-)